# C - Segmentation fault on creating "2D Array"

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, multidimensional-array

I have to create a "2D Array" with x rows (User can decide how many) and for each row there should be a random amount of columns, which will be generated random, so it will look like this:

```
2 - 4 - 6

1 - 2 - 8 - 9 - 2 - 3

1 - 2
```

the amount of columns for each row will be saved in sizes[i]. The numbers in the 2d array will be generated randomly. I looked here through stackoverflow, and finding some solutions regarding dynamic memory allocation, but somehow I always end up with a 'Segmentation fault' and I can't really see a major flaw in my code. So any help would be appriciated. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int** create_array(int* sizes, int rows){
    int** array;
    array=(int**) malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        array[i]=(int*) malloc((sizes[i])*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sizes[i];j++){
            array[i][j]=(((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))*20);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

void print_array(int** array, int* sizes){
    int rows=sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(sizes[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sizes[i];j++){
            printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int rows = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Wie viele Zeilen möchten Sie erzeugen?");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    int sizes[rows];
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        sizes[i]=(((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))*9+1);
        printf(" %d ",sizes[i]);
    }
    int** arr;
    arr=create_array(sizes,rows);
    print_array(arr,sizes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `create_array`, this looks suspicions: `for(int j=0;i<sizes[i];j++){` (I guess you want to compare `j`, not `i` with `sizes[i]`). The same in `print_array`.

Comment: You have a typo `for(int j=0;i<sizes[i];j++){`

Comment: Also, `sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(sizes[0])` will give you "bad" result, you cannot calculate the size of array (passed as pointer).

Comment: I feel pretty bad for overseeing this huge typo heh, Thanks guys! @KirilKirov I see it now... Do you have any advice how to solve this 'better'? Because I don't really want to give the function another argument..

Comment: @Kuro95 - no other ways, that I can think of. You need to pass one more parameter (or use some `struct`s instead, but the idea still remains the same - you need to have the size somewhere).

Comment: @Kuro95 you can create a `struct` and store the extra information in it, and then only pass an array of `struct` as a pointer to the functions, but I would recommend you don't make it more complex than it is, just pass the extra parameter.

Comment: Code is working fine now. Thanks guys!

Comment: regarding this (and similar) lines: array=(int**) malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));  1) for several reasons, do not cast the returned value from malloc (and family)  2) always check the returned value from malloc (and family) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: 'scanf("%d",&rows);'  the code should always check the returned value from scanf (and family) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: this line: sizes[i]=(((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))*9+1); can be greatly simplified to: sizes[i]=(rand()%9) +1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a mistake in

```
for(int j=0;i<sizes[i];j++)
```

it should be

```
for(int j=0;j<sizes[i];j++)
```

It would have been easier to spot that if you use more whitespaces like

```
for (int j = 0 ; i < sizes[i] ; j++)
/*               ^ see, here it's very clear now
```

and also, don't forget to call `free` after you are done using the data.

Change this function too

```
void print_array(int** array, int* sizes){
    int rows =sizeof(sizes)/sizeof(sizes[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<sizes[i];j++){
            printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

there is no way to determine the count of elements in `sizes`, you must pass that as an argument

```
void print_array(int** array, int* sizes, int rows)
{
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<sizes[i];j++){
            printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**note**: there is no need to cast `malloc` in c, it could hide bugs.